# How to scroll down to last line in Vim?

Tags: vim

My Rails `production.log` has 2000000 lines. How can I scroll down to the last line with Vim?

I scroll down with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> but it's not fast enough.

Comment: `:$` goes to the last line.

Comment: FWIW, if you're dealing with a 2m line logfile, VIM might not be what you want. Try a pager such as `less`.

Answer (score 13):

#### Alternative motions

Note that you can prefix motions like `j` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> with a number (multiplier), called `[count]` in the (excellent) `:help`. That gets you around a large buffer fast.

Another beneficial, but less known command is `N%`, to jump to a percentage in the file, e.g. the middle with `50%`.

#### Best solution

But your particular problem is indeed best addressed by `G`, or `:$` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### Additional help

With such a large file, navigation in Vim may be sluggish. Have a look at the [LargeFile - Edit large files quickly](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) plugin, which changes some options to speed up Vim.

#### Tips

If you're new to Vim (and its navigation and editing commands), you should spend 30 minutes on the `vimtutor` that comes with it (see `:help vimtutor` inside Vim). Then, there are several good resources, cheatsheets, and vi / Vim tutorials out there on the net. http://vimcasts.org/ has several short entertaining episodes that go beyond the basics.

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-vi-vim-jump-to-end-of-file/):

> To move to end of file just type G (press ESC and type capital G):

You can also go to a specific line with the line number followed by G, for example to go to line 123 you would do

```
123G
```

Answer (score 4):

`G` is the key. if you want to open the file with cursor positioning on the last line, you can:

```
vim +  foo.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Further to the other answers, if the first thing you do when you open the logfile is jump to the end, have vim open the file straight at the end with:

```
vim /path/to/logfile +
```

Alternatively, as in my comment above, try opening it in a pager such as `less` if you're not actually editing the file. Again, you can jump straight to the end of the file from the command line:

```
less +G /path/to/logfile
```

More generally, both these forms (with the `+` argument) allow you to specify a command to run on startup.

`vim` defaults to jumping to the end of the file if no command is given, whereas `less` requires you to specify the `G` command. Both `less` and `vim` support searching for a specific string (e.g. a date) on opening the file with:

```
vim +/2014-02-28 /path/to/logfile
less +/2014-02-28 /path/to/logfile
```